# ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I can't find the problem in the code, but it says at the end of that "Missing number, treated as zero"

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=stealth,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm,
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=6.0,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=4.5,
xticklabels={,,1,,,4},
ytick={\empty},]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (6.,4.5);
\fill[fill=black,fill opacity=0.20000000298023224] (1.0045836142718776,1.4243770120110515) -- (1.0045836142718776,0.) -- (4,0) -- (3.996318624435588,0.5559251076370629) -- (3.764797284337927,0.5803447447339725) -- (3.5176114060500536,0.609277926604037) -- (3.0369721982680775,0.676251412660451) -- (2.7554549479957773,0.7294953956208646) -- (2.535734167295445,0.7672558117999624) -- (2.309147112198228,0.8185829277750029) -- (2.0550949595134687,0.8866827343500797) -- (1.8010428068287099,0.9697221311676422) -- (1.5401243797470656,1.0769669337835905) -- (1.3135373246498483,1.1965218380095286) -- (1.1487467391245991,1.306084296440851) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=1.2,smooth,samples=100,domain=6-6:6.1] plot(\x,{10/(2*(\x)+5*sqrt((\x)))});
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.0045836142718776,1.4243770120110515)-- (1.0045836142718776,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (3.996318624435216,0.5559251076932408)-- (4.,0.);
\draw (-0.4,0.02) node[anchor=north west] {$O$};
\draw (2.2424396505089295,0.6291874906703163) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{R}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please try to copy and compile your posted code. It doesn‘t, right? Please add the vital missing parts. Thank you

Comment: If I minimally complete your code, I get an error but not the error you're reporting. Instead, I get `! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide \`10' by \`0.0', but I cannot divide any number by \`0.0' (in '{10/(2*(0.0)+5*sqrt((0.0)))}').` Note that if you get multiple errors, it is the first one you should pay attention to. Nothing after the first error is reliable either in typeset output or logging.

Comment: @RIRM506 Altough it seems that the problem was found in this case, please consider providing a full code example next time, not just a code snippet. It is vital that others know which packages and document class you use, so that they can *exactly* reproduce the problem you encounter. everything else is mere guesswork.

Comment: Off-topic: Do replace `\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.0045836142718776, 1.4243770120110515)-- (1.0045836142718776,0);` and `\draw [line width=1.2pt] (3.996318624435216, 0.5559251076932408)-- (4.,0.);` with `\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.,1.424)-- (1.,0.);` and `\draw [line width=1.2pt] (4.,0.557)-- (4.,0.);`, respectively. More generally, do yourself a big favor and don't specify point locations with more than 2 or 3 digits of precision. E.g., instead of `3.0369721982680775` and `0.20000000298023224`, write `3.037` and `0.2`. By removing visual clutter, you'll make it easier to spot real bugs.

Comment: In addition to @JasperHabicht 's comment, for `pgfplots` you need to specify the `compat` version, too, as that makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea what this is meant to look like or if your settings are different. I make only two claims for this. First, it compiles without error. Second, it doesn't do that weird singularity thing at the beginning.

Whether this solves the error you reported getting, I don't know as I was unable to reproduce it. Instead, I got

```
! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `10' by `0.0', but I cannot divide any number by `0.0' (in '{10/(2*(0.0)+5*sqrt((0.0)))}')
```

This is not an unreasonable complaint.

```
domain=6-6:6.1
```

I admit I have no idea what the point of the `6-6` is intended to be. All it does is slow compilation while `pgfmath` calculated `0.0` and makes it less clear what's happening.

```
domain=0.01:6.1
```

works. You can start nearer zero, but you get the weird singularity effect I mentioned.

I assume this code is exported from something else. That's obviously fine, but if you pay attention to the errors it will help you find the bugs. You might also want to see if you can limit the precision in the output because calculating coordinates to 16 decimal places only makes the code harder for humans to understand. Even if human beings could discern the differences, which we obviously can't, `pgfmath` cannot manage them and that level of detail is simply lost in processing. (Actually, a chunk of it will disappear just by *storing* the points. The calculations will then reduce it further.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=stealth,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
  \begin{axis}[
    x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=6.0,
    ymin=-0.5,
    ymax=4.5,
    xticklabels={,,1,,,4},
    ytick={\empty},]
    \clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (6.,4.5);
    \fill[fill=black,fill opacity=0.20000000298023224] (1.0045836142718776,1.4243770120110515) -- (1.0045836142718776,0.) -- (4,0) -- (3.996318624435588,0.5559251076370629) -- (3.764797284337927,0.5803447447339725) -- (3.5176114060500536,0.609277926604037) -- (3.0369721982680775,0.676251412660451) -- (2.7554549479957773,0.7294953956208646) -- (2.535734167295445,0.7672558117999624) -- (2.309147112198228,0.8185829277750029) -- (2.0550949595134687,0.8866827343500797) -- (1.8010428068287099,0.9697221311676422) -- (1.5401243797470656,1.0769669337835905) -- (1.3135373246498483,1.1965218380095286) -- (1.1487467391245991,1.306084296440851) -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=1.2,smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:6.1] plot(\x,{10/(2*(\x)+5*sqrt((\x)))});
    \draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.0045836142718776,1.4243770120110515)-- (1.0045836142718776,0);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt] (3.996318624435216,0.5559251076932408)-- (4.,0.);
    \draw (-0.4,0.02) node[anchor=north west] {$O$};
    \draw (2.2424396505089295,0.6291874906703163) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{R}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled plot, though whether it is the right plot is another question]

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is addressed and solved in the @cfr nice answer (+1), however, it can be avoided with just remove error in defining of domain definition and use `pdfplots` way to draw functions. By use of the `fillbetween` library of `pgfplots` package  the diagram code is much shorter:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}  % <---
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    label style = {anchor=north east},
    xmin=-0.5,  xmax=6.0,
    ymin=-0.5,  ymax=4.5,
    xticklabels={,,1,,,4},
    ytick={\empty},
    domain=0:6,   % <---
    samples=100,  
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.2pt},
            ]
    
\addplot[name path =A]  {10/(2*x+5*sqrt(x))};                 % <---
\path    [name path=B]  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
                        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);  % <---
\addplot [gray!30] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:4}];

\draw [line width=1.2pt]    (1,0)-- (1,{10/(2*1+5*sqrt(1))})
                            (4,0)-- (4,{10/(2*4+5*sqrt(4))});
\node[below left]   at (0,0)        {0};
\node               at (2.5,0.4)    {$\mathbf{R}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE main differences in comparison to yours are marked by `% <---`.

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding to `xticks` labels to my opinion it has mare sense to show tick at `x=0` by use of the `extra x tick` and remove label written with node at diagram origin:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    label style = {anchor=north east},
    xmin=-0.5,  xmax=6.0,
    ymin=-0.5,  ymax=4.5,
    xticklabels={,,1,,,4},
    extra x ticks={0},   % <---
    extra x tick style={tick label style = {fill=white, inner sep=2pt}},    % <---
    ytick={\empty},
    domain=0:6, samples=100,
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.2pt},
            ]

\addplot[name path =A]  {10/(2*x+5*sqrt(x))};
\path    [name path=B]  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
                        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot [gray!30] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:4}];

\draw [line width=1.2pt]    (1,0)-- (1,{10/(2*1+5*sqrt(1))})
                            (4,0)-- (4,{10/(2*4+5*sqrt(4))});
\node   at (2.5,0.4)    {$\mathbf{R}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. While you're at it, you may also want to replace `{$O$}` ("Capital-O") with `{$0$}` ("zero").

Comment: @Mico,I just copy OP code ... but you are right. It has (somehow) more sense :-), Corrected now.

Comment: An answer which actually knows what it's doing :). What does `pgfplots` do with the division by `0` case?

Comment: @cfr, this about dividing with zero is quite mysterious ... I didn't figured out (yet) why this works. I remember, that in general I can prevent this problem with defining also `y` domain, for example by `restrict y to domain=-2:100`.

Comment: @Zarko Hmm. Another mystery. Here you're not even adding that, unless I've missed it. There's no justice that your answer has fewer votes than mine.

Comment: @cfr, I just check some my older answers, using `pgfplots` version 1.16, and also works without restriction of y domain. Fid I was lucky and samples in domain miss zero? I do not know. This seems to be a question for package author.