# How to find "missing number, treated as zero" error in a code

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, tikz-pic

There's an error on the end of the code and it says that there is "missing number, treated as zero" and i have no idea what that means. how do i find it in this code?

```
\begin{axis}[
x=1.3333333333333333cm,y=1.1627906976744187cm,
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-2.0,
xmax=4.0,
ymin=-2.0,
ymax=2.3,
xtick={\empty},
ytick={\empty},]
\clip(-2.,-2.) rectangle (4.,2.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.0:4.0] plot(\x,{(\x)^(2)-1});
\draw[line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=4.0000000012539686E-6:4.0] plot(\x,{ln((\x))});
\draw (1.8855684490090832,2.1448633485685624) node[anchor=north west] {$y = g(x)$};
\draw (2.3,1) node[anchor=north west] {$y = f(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700292/5764

Comment: @Werner I couldn't reproduce the reported error using the code in the question you linked. No idea if this is different.

Comment: it's okay i just edited the domain and the error was fixed thank you!

Comment: Off-topic: Do yourself a big favor and don't specify numbers with with 12 and more digits of precision. E.g., do replace `domain=4.0000000012539686E-6:4.0` with `domain=0.0:4.0`. If nothing else, the second formulation should tip you off to the possibility that the directive `plot(\x,{ln((\x))})` might cause trouble. If, for some reason, you want to plot a value for `ln(`x)` for a very small (but positive) value of `\x`, specifying `domain=0.001:4.0` will get the job done.

Comment: this is noted! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mess of `pgfplots` and `tikz` ways of drawing of diagrams. Please stick with just one. I would select `pgfplots`. At this I would consider [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700299/) in given link in the @Werner comment:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text=black, inner sep=2pt, anchor=north west, pos=#1}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits=0.1,  % added
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    label style = {anchor=north east},
    ymin=-2.0,
    xtick={\empty},
    ytick={\empty},
    samples=100,    no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
        ]
\addplot +[domain=-2:2] {(x)^2-1} node[lbl=1] {$y = g(x)$};
\addplot +[domain= 0:4] {ln(x)} node[lbl=0.85] {$y = f(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In comparison to your code fragment in above proposed solution is used (only) `pgfplots` syntax for drawing curve. Beside this are done some small changes ad adding labels to curves. Also note changes in defined domains.