# removing lines from a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-pic

Is there any way I can remove the straight lines from this image?

it should look like this (first image)

[image]

but it appears to be like this second one

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-3.5,
xmax=3.5,
ymin=-3.0,
ymax=3.0,
xtick={-pi, -2*pi/3,-pi/3, pi/3, (2*pi)/3, pi},
xticklabels={$-\pi$, $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$,$-\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\pi$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\pi$},
domain=-pi:pi,
ytick={\empty},]
\clip(-3.5,-3.) rectangle (3.5,3.);
\draw[line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.5:-0.01] plot(\x,{tan((2*(\x)+3.14/2)*180/pi)});
\draw[line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:3.5] plot(\x,{tan((2*(\x)+3.14/2)*180/pi)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (-5.2,0.69) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please give a full example which can be copied and compiled directly by other people.

Answer (score 3):

- You should learn from received answer how to draw such (or similar) answer ...
- For example, on your one of previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701114/how-to-find-missing-number-treated-as-zero-error-in-a-code), you got answer which solve your problem (why you not accept them? what you missed in it? why you not edit your question and make it more clear as you was asked?)
- Please, consider gotten advise: don't mix `pgfplots` and pure `tikz` if it is really necessary. Especially not at drawing of curves! Compare how curves are drawn in My MWE and how you do you in your code fragment!
- It is time to read `pgfplots` package documentation. There are a lot of examples, how to draw different diagrams
- And not the last, please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is. May times are sources of your problems in document preamble (used packages, definitions etc.) which are now unknown to us (participants on this site)
- Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,                            % <---
    enlargelimits=0.05,                     % <---
%
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
%
    xmin=-1.1*pi,   xmax=1.1*pi,            % <---
    ymin=-5,        ymax=5,                 % <---
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,              % <===
%
    xtick distance=pi/3,
    minor x tick num=1,
    xticklabels={ ,$-\pi$, $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $-\frac{\pi}{3}$, 
                  ,$\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\pi$},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white, inner sep=1pt},
    extra x ticks = 0,
    ytick=\empty,
%
    trig format plots=rad,                  % <---
    domain=-pi:pi, 
    samples=501, no marks,                  % <---
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=blue}
            ]
\addplot {tan(2*x + pi/2};                  % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- Sorry, it is not clear what should denote node `$f$` and where it should be placed, so I drop it out (but I can return it to correct place when you will clarify your question)

[image]

**Edit:**

- corrected are `xtick`  positions and labels and remove `yticklabel`
- the above MWE is a wee bit redesigned (according to my taste): arrows heads at each function segments are dropped
- in the case, that you like with arrows heads to emphasize, that each function segment start at minus infinity and end at plus infinity, than you need plot each function segment separately:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,                          
    enlargelimits=0.05,                     
%
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
%
    xmin=-1.1*pi,   xmax=1.1*pi,          
    ymin=-5,        ymax=5,                
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,              % <---
%
    xtick distance=pi/3,
    minor x tick num=1,
    xticklabels={ ,$-\pi$, $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $-\frac{\pi}{3}$,
                  ,$\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\pi$},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white, inner sep=1pt},
    extra x ticks = 0,
    ytick=\empty,
%
    trig format plots=rad,                  
    samples=501, no marks,                      % <---
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=blue, <->}% <---
            ]
\addplot [domain=-pi:-pi/2] {tan(2*x + pi/2)};  % <---
\addplot [domain=-pi/2:0]   {tan(2*x + pi/2)};  % <---
\addplot [domain= 0:pi/2]   {tan(2*x + pi/2)};  % <---
\addplot [domain= pi/2:pi]  {tan(2*x + pi/2)};  % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Very good solution and explication.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro, thank you very much! I hope that answer will be of some help to OP and that he will learning  something from it too. I know, that first steps into use of `pgfplots` package can be steep.