pgfplots: How to fill an area under a data set
I have a pretty big data file (8192 lines) and when i try to fill the area ander the function it fills the area above. How can i fix this?
A piece of the data file:
E   Ch
228.2592147 820
228.4568005 854
228.6543863 824
228.8519722 866
229.049558  754
229.2471438 765
229.4447296 829
229.6423155 827
229.8399013 814
230.0374871 831
230.235073  744
230.4326588 717
230.6302446 796
230.8278305 746
231.0254163 740
231.2230021 769
231.420588  767

Here's my code:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis line style={black},
        xmin=60,xmax=400,
        xlabel=$E\,(\si{\kilo \electronvolt})$,
        ymin=0,ymax=55000,
        ylabel= \text{contagens},
        ]
        \addplot[fill,blue,smooth] table[x=E,y=Ch]{Ba.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

and here's the output


Welcome to TeX.SE!. Please make your code fragment to complete small document which we can test as it is.  For test wee need only few data. Fill diagram with color (should be) independent from number of data. So far your code doesn't contain instruction for fill diagram ...

AN example about how to fill area under data you can find on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700299/ as well in pgfplots packages are many example about this.

@Zarko i did that but im still getting the same output

Sorry, but I can't confirm that, you not show code(in form of MWE) of your try. So I don't believe in your claim. Your code fragment not indicate this. You need to provide workable WME (Minimal Working Example.

@Zarko sorry but that was litterally the whole code. I removed the \tikzexternalize and it works now

I’m voting to close this question because problem is not possible to reproduce and OP inform us in comment that (s)he solve problem by omitting instruction \tikzexternalize.

@JoãoSantos If the problem is solved with \tikzexternalize, it means that you had an old wrong version of the image, tikz did not recognized a change in the code and still made the old version appear.
